# Ruby on Rails routing Error: Missing :game_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to ruby an I try to develop something currently.

But I got an small error when it comes to routing.

my routes.rb

```
resources :games do
resources :matches
end
```

game.rb

```
has_many :matches
```

match.rb

```
belongs_to :game
```

rake routes

```
new_game_match GET    /games/:game_id/matches/new(.:format)      matches#new
```

where error occurs:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Match', new_game_match_path %>
```

what error tells:

```
No route matches [GET] "/games/matches/new"
```

now i have no idea why he doesn't route the game_id with it an why it raises this error..

anyone can help me plz?

if it helps, both models and controller were scaffolded but matches controller was edited to fit relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new_game_match_path` helper expects a `game` argument from which to pull the `game_id` parameter.

Given a game with id `123`, stored in a variable called `@game`, you would invoke it like this:

```
new_game_match_path(@game)
```

Which would return a path like this:

```
/games/123/matches/new
```

When you nest routes this way, you're making a new `match` for a *specific* `game`, and without including the `@game` parameter there is no way to build the URL.

You could also use the array syntax. The following is equivalent to `new_game_match_path(@game)`:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Match', [:new, @game, :match] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply a `game` object to your helper, as in `new_game_match_path(game)`. You can see in the `rake routes` output that it expects a `game_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `matches` route is nested within `game`. This means that a match makes sense only in context of a game.

Provide a valid game to your url helper

```
<%= link_to 'Add Match', new_game_match_path(@game) %>
```